# I get an error when creating user's role in ASP .NET MVC Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I did everything, as shown in the instructions: [Role Based Security in ASP.NET MVC 5 Web Applications](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet-mvc/1102/aspnet-mvc-role-based-security), but inside the action got the following error in **Register** action of **AccountController**:

```
if (result.Succeeded)
{
    //Assign Role to user Here 
    await this.UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(user.Id, model.Name /*ERROR HERE*/); 
    //Ends Here
    await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

Error message:

> Error 2   'HelloWorld.Models.RegisterViewModel' does not contain a definition for 'Name' and no extension method 'Name' accepting a first argument of type 'HelloWorld.Models.RegisterViewModel' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> C:\Users\IliA\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\HelloWorld\HelloWorld\HelloWorld\Controllers\AccountController.cs  163 74  HelloWorld

Comment: It's an error in the ViewModel, part of your application. Does it contain a Name? Or maybe a Username?  Show us the class of `model`.

Comment: I'm an idiot. I forgot to add automatically implemented property "Name". Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the end of step 1:

> locate the RegisterViewModel class and add the following string property:
>   `public string Name { get; set; }`

Comment: Please, can you help me again? I have an error in `@Html.DropDownList("Name")` Error message: **The ViewData item that has the key 'Name' is of type 'System.String' but must be of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>'.**

Comment: Thanks! The bug is fixed after Migration and Updating Database.

Comment: @Henk Thanks. Your suggestion solved a similar issue I had.